# android: mindboggling behaviour of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is truly driving me nuts.

I am new to android development, but quite an experienced developer. Maybe I don't know android studio well enough???

I am trying to develop my first app. It will be pretty simple first. I have a splash screen, then a "landing screen", where the user needs to select something and then a map appears.

I run my app with an emulator executing "run" (click on the icon) in studio's tool bar. I have a simple default configuration "app" which launches the default activity.

The app crashes right now. In the "Android" log output I get:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
            at co.myapp.ui.android.user.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:33)
```

BUT THE CODE ON LINE 33 IS **COMMENTED**!!!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);   //new
    //getActionBar().hide();  //this is line 33!
```

I cleaned and rebuilt the project, restarted studio....

I don't get what's going on. I suspect it has to do with the somewhat intransparent debug/main/ configurations of android-studio...(the Gradle console output is full of `:app:xxxDebugxxx` logs...????) but really I am baffled, and so blocked now I don't know where to continue...

What's going on here???

Comment: Which gradle version are you using? Because 1.0.0 for example was a version full of bugs!

Comment: Run clean assembleDebug tasks using gradlew on CLI. Use --info switch if needed but verify success on build. Then rerun activity n u should have clean line # from symbolic portion of build

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it myself but what finally helped:

Create a new project and handy-ish copy my files via commandline over, restart android - it seems to be working again.

I have worked many years with eclipse and this strange android-studio doesn't feel right. Nevertheless I am afraid I would be missing out on tutorials etc (the whole android documentation seems to be running on android studio). Also I am not clear if I'd get any emulator functionality with eclipse (or any other environment, say vi....), without which it seems cumbersome to develop android apps.

Comment: You can still use Eclipse if you want to.  There's no requirement to use Android Studio.  Emulators will still work.

Comment: I wonder if you cleaned, and rebuilt your project.  I would suggest using Android Studio.  Eclipse is deprecated (officially).  Generally I find AS much more reliable then Eclipse (and I literally wrote the book on ADT, so would be biased if there was a reason).

Comment: @Booger - I did, as mentioned in the question. I must have changed some weird configuration, there's no other explanation. Didn't know eclipse had been deprecated. I'll stick to AS for now. I may have been feeling "advanced" user too soon and may not be working the AS way yet (proof of this is going over the command line to try to fix things...). Can you point me to a good page explaining the whole debug/main/release configurations? You seem to be the man. Thanks.